# C# XAttribute with whitespaces

Tags: c#, .net, linq, xml-parsing, linq-to-xml

How can I have whitespaces on XAttribute, here is my code snippet:

```
new XElement("SubstitutionAttribute", new XAttribute("SubNetwork Group",subNetBox.Text))
```

What I am trying to achieve in xml:

```
<SubstitutionAttribute name="SubNetwork Group" value="Something" />
```

Best regards,

Hugo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your example is failing is because the constructor for `XAttribute` expects the name of the attribute and its value.

So with `new XElement("SubstitutionAttribute", new XAttribute("SubNetwork Group",subNetBox.Text))` you are acutally declaring only one attribute with the name "Subnetwork Group" and the value subNetBox.Text (`<SubstitutionAttribute SubNetwork Group="Something" />`). This is invalid XML as you can't have spaces in an attribute name.

What I think you are trying to do should be done with two attributes - one called `name` and the other called `value`:

```
new XElement("SubstitutionAttribute", 
    new XAttribute("name", "SubNetwork Group"), 
    new XAttribute("value", subNetBox.Text));
```